# Application crashes when logging in using facebook or google account

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, facebook-login, google-signin

I have followed a tutorial to create an aplication for login using facebook and google using firebase."sign in with email" button works fine,  But When I try to login using google or facebook the application get crashed.

Here is my MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  implements  View.OnClickListener{

private  static final int RC_SIGN_IN=0;
FirebaseAuth auth;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    FirebaseAuth auth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    if(auth.getCurrentUser()!=null)
    {
        Log.d("AUTH",auth.getCurrentUser().getEmail());
    }
    else {
        startActivityForResult(AuthUI.getInstance()
                .createSignInIntentBuilder().setProviders(
                        AuthUI.FACEBOOK_PROVIDER,
                        AuthUI.GOOGLE_PROVIDER,
                        AuthUI.EMAIL_PROVIDER

                ).build(), RC_SIGN_IN);
    }

    findViewById(R.id.btnLogout).setOnClickListener(this);
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode==RC_SIGN_IN)
    {
        if(resultCode==RESULT_OK)
        {
            Log.d("AUTH",auth.getCurrentUser().getEmail());
        }
        else
        {
            Log.d("AUTH","Not authenticated");
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if(view.getId()==R.id.btnLogout)
    {
        AuthUI.getInstance().signOut(this).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                Log.d("AUTH","User logged Out");
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

}

build.gradle(app) file

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.ranjit.authenticate"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:0.4.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and below is my logcat for the application

```
08-21 03:09:24.419 23408-23408/com.example.ranjit.authenticate E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                             Process: com.example.ranjit.authenticate, PID: 23408
                                                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=0, result=-1, data=Intent {  }} to activity {com.example.ranjit.authenticate/com.example.ranjit.authenticate.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3532)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3575)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:139)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1341)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
                                                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                              Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                 at com.example.ranjit.authenticate.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:50)
                                                                                 at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5603)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3528)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3575) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:139) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1341) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257) 
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609) 
                                                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

08-21 03:09:30.779 23408-23421/com.example.ranjit.authenticate W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have Null pointer exception in the method.
It's probably the way you access *auth*

> ```
>         Log.d("AUTH",auth.getCurrentUser().getEmail()
> ```